# Using the TTS Synthesizer in iOS when the app is ALREADY on the background

Tags: ios, audio, background, playback

I would like to play a sound and use the AVSpeechSynthesizer to speak out some strings. The point is that I want these to happen when the device is already locked and then some events happen which triggers them.

I've found lots of info about how to play sound on the background, but this means that playback starts when the app is active and then the playback could continue, if the screen is being locked (after the start of playback). I've done all the tricks but can't hear a sound, which is triggered when the device is locked (and app is already on the background). However this works with iOS 8.3 simulator almost out-of-the-box, but not with a device.

So how to resolve this? Should I actually use some notification stuff to produce the desired outcome? I'm not too familiar with the notifications, so is there any other workarounds or is the notifications way easier than I think?

Cheers,
Mikko